# How can I make a series of tuples?

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas I have two columns of data representing longitude and latitude. I want to turn this into a single column where each element is a 2-tuple (lon, lat). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could `apply` `tuple` on `axis=1`

```
In [180]: df
Out[180]:
    lat   lon
0  23.1  43.4
1  33.3  99.9

In [181]: df.apply(lambda x : tuple(x), axis=1)
Out[181]:
0    (23.1, 43.4)
1    (33.3, 99.9)
dtype: object
```

Or `zip` the two columns?

```
In [182]: zip(df['lat'], df['lon'])
Out[182]:
[(23.100000000000001, 43.399999999999999),
 (33.299999999999997, 99.900000000000006)]
```